# Have a delete button, must be hit twice to update page in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

So I have a "delete record button" in any other browser it is functioning correctly. Deletes the record from SQL, and properly updates the page. My thought is that IE is not updating the page with the js event, and deleting the record from view. If I hit it once, doesn't update page, twice it does. Hit it once, and refresh the page manually it is gone from view properly. Anyone ever heard of IE doing this? Nothing in the debugger is telling me of an error. The delete event is below, if this is where it could be mishandled. Does IE need a special filter to handle events like this? Thanks!

```
// button in question creation
function create_delete_button( oObj ) {
return '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteItem(' + oObj.aData[0] + ')"/>';}

// post to db the deletion
function DeleteItem( id ) {
$.post( "/Data/DeleteItem?Id=" + id, GetUpdatedItems() );}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you've shown would not update the page in any way in any browser - it doesn't include any DOM manipulation or navigation at all. The whole point of Ajax (and I assume `$.post()` is the jQuery Ajax method) is that it makes a request without refreshing the page.

So I assume the problem must be with the `GetUpdatedItems()` function that you don't show, specifically in the way you are calling it. Try removing the parentheses after `GetUpdatedItems`, like this:

```
$.post( "/Data/DeleteItem?Id=" + id, GetUpdatedItems );
//                    parentheses removed from here ^
```

jQuery's [`$.post()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) expects a callback function as its second argument. That is, you are supposed to pass a reference to a function and then jQuery will call that function for you after the post completes.

What you are doing in the code in the question is *calling* the function immediately and passing its result to `$.post()`, so that means `GetUpdatedItems()` gets executed *before* you do the post to delete the item. If `GetUpdatedItems()` also does an ajax request then you can't guarantee the timing of which request comes back first.

> *"Nothing in the debugger is telling me of an error."*

The particular problem I identified isn't a JavaScript error, so it wouldn't be reported in the debugger. It's valid code, it just doesn't have the effect you want.

Comment: Removing the parentheses of GetUpdatedItems() worked in IE! It is properly updating the page via click of the delete button. Any idea why it was specific to IE?

Comment: Not really, though _with_ the parentheses I think it was mostly luck that it worked in the other browsers - removing the parens isn't a workaround, it is the correct way to do it. As I mentioned in the answer, if `GetUpdatedItems()` also does an ajax request you can't really guarantee the order that the responses come back.